# Can a custom PXSelectAttribute use different entities in BQL

Tags: acumatica

For example, if a value of a field in the cache is "Account", build the SELECT BQL and return a list Accounts.  If the value of a field in the cache is "Attribute", then build the SELECT BQL and return the list of Attributes.
Can this be done?  
In my case, I attempt to build a custom type which encapsulates a description and a code value, much similar to the standard PXSelector.  So my attempt is to build a wrapper for the type which is returned from the custom selector.  So far no success.

Comment: You can try to create a new DAC with PXProjectionAttribute which will combain your DAC's and set selector to that DAC

Comment: Have a look at Sell Price screen. Where the lookup screen is dependent on selected entity e.g. Customer or Customer Class.